# mongoose calling .find inside a pre('save') hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Currently I'm trying to do the following:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 ...
 name : String
 ...
});

ItemSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  try{
     let count = await ItemSchema.find({name : item.name}).count().exec();
     ....
     return Promise.resolve();
  }catch(err){
     return Promise.reject(err)
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

But I Just get the following Error:

> TypeError: ItemSchema.find is not a function

How do I call the .find() method inside my post('save') middleware ?
 (I know, that there is a unique property on Schmemas. I have to do it this way to suffix the name string if it already exists)

mongoose version : 5.1.3
nodejs version : 8.1.1
system : ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried to use `this.find` to replace `ItemSchema.find`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`find` static method is available on models, while `ItemSchema` is schema.

It should be either:

```
ItemSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  try{
     let count = await Item.find({name : item.name}).count().exec();
     ....
  }catch(err){
     throw err;
  }
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
module.exports = Item;
```

Or:

```
ItemSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  try{
     const Item = this.constructor;
     let count = await Item.find({name : item.name}).count().exec();
     ....
  }catch(err){
         throw err;
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

Notice that `Promise.resolve()` is redundant in `async` function, it already returns resolved promise in case of success, so is `Promise.reject`.

Comment: thanks for your Notice, I'm new in the world of async/await

Answer (score 0):

We can declare the model name first, then use it to get the model instance by name, then we can use the static function of the model. ex: find, findOne ...etc

```
const modelName = 'Item'; // <---- Hint
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 ...
 name : String
 ...
});

ItemSchema.pre(
  'save',
  { document: true },
  async function() {
    try {
      let count = await this.model(modelName) // <-- Hint
                            .find({name : item.name})
                            .count()
                            .exec();
      
    } catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model(modelName, ItemSchema);
```